# Xilinx Vivado IBUF instantiation

Tags: xilinx, vivado

I have a question regarding Xilinx Vivado. I don't really know how to explain it, but I'll give it a try and hopefully you will know what I mean.

In Vivado, you can instantiate primitives for example an IDDR. I need 15 IDDRs, is it enough when I instantiate one? The instantiation looks like this:

```
  IBUFDS_inst : IBUFDS
   generic map (
      DIFF_TERM => FALSE, -- Differential Termination 
      IBUF_LOW_PWR => TRUE, -- Low power (TRUE) vs. performance (FALSE) setting for referenced I/O standards
      IOSTANDARD => "DEFAULT")
   port map (
      O => O,  -- Buffer output
      I => DIN1P,  -- Diff_p buffer input (connect directly to top-level port)
      IB => DIN1N -- Diff_n buffer input (connect directly to top-level port)
   );
```

But I also need IDDRs for DIN2P, DIN2N till DIN15P,DIN15N. Do I have to instantiate this component 15 times?

Comment: Think of each instantiation as a virtual device on a virdual PCB.  The value before the ":" is the reference designator, and the IBUFDS is the part number.  You would need 16 buffers on a real board, so you need 16 buffers in your VHDL as well.  You can use a generate statement to create them all at once to save some typing.

Comment: @crj11 so I can just call them IBUFDS_inst : IBUFDS1 and so on?

Comment: The correct format would be BUF1 : IBUFDS, BUF2 : IBUFDS, BUF3 : IBUFDS ...  The BUFx is the equivalent to the reference designator on a schematic and IBUFDS is equivalent to the part number.

Comment: Thanks I used the generate statement at it works. Doing it like "BUF1 : IBUFDS, BUF2 : IBUFDS, BUF3 : IBUFDS" gave me errors

Comment: I guess I should have been more specific.  The format is  BUF1 : IBUFDS <generic map + port map>;  BUF2 : IBUFDS  <generic map + port map>; BUF3 : IBUFDS  <generic map + port map>; .  The commas were meant to imply a sequence of instantiations.

Comment: @crj11 ah ok. That looks like alot of unnecessary code. The generate statement is way better in terms of structure

Comment: I agree that the generate statement is the better way to instantiate any repetitive structure such as your input buffers.

Comment: @crj11 I think you should put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to instantiate multiple repetitive structures such as multiple IBUF is with the for generate statement. Here is an example for the above IBUF.

```
IBUFDSgen: for i in 9 downto 0 generate --instantiates 10 IBUFs

  IBUFDS_inst : IBUFDS
   generic map (
      DIFF_TERM => FALSE, -- Differential Termination 
      IBUF_LOW_PWR => TRUE, -- Low power (TRUE) vs. performance (FALSE) setting for referenced I/O standards
      IOSTANDARD => "DEFAULT")
   port map (
      O => O(i),  -- Buffer output
      I => DIN1P(i),  -- Diff_p buffer input (connect directly to top-level port)
      IB => DIN1N(i) -- Diff_n buffer input (connect directly to top-level port)
   );
end generate IBUFDSgen;
```